# Patroni Postgres Cluster, what does 'TL' mean in the output of 'patronictl list'

Tags: postgresql-cluster, patroni

Executing.

```
patronictl list
```

Produces

```
+ Cluster: psql-core03-uat-kong (6867488892458676291) ------+----+-----------+
|         Member         |      Host     |  Role  |  State  | TL | Lag in MB |
+------------------------+---------------+--------+---------+----+-----------+
| psql-podname-blahbla-0 |  ##.##.###.## | Leader | running | 46 |           |
| psql-podname-blahbla-1 |  ##.##.###.## |        | running | 21 |     14288 |
| psql-podname-blahbla-2 |  ##.##.###.## |        | running | 46 |         0 |
+------------------------+---------------+--------+---------+----+-----------+
```

Does anyone know what the column 'TL' stands for, means?  Scoured the manuals but no joy.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick [search](https://github.com/zalando/patroni/search?q=TL) of the [source](https://github.com/zalando/patroni) indicates that it means [timeline](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-TIMELINES).